# Default Value For Dropdown List

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to set a default value for the DropDown list as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BillId", "")
```

The user doesn't necessarily need to select something but the list throws an error

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'BillId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'
```

if a value is not selected and the box is left on it's default blank state.

My controllers as follows:

```
    Function Create(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        ViewBag.id = id
        Dim job As Job = New Job
        job.CustomerId = id
        job.JobAmount = 0
        job.JobDate = Date.Now()
        job.JobStatus = "Active"

        Dim BillList = New List(Of Bill)()

        Dim BillQuery = From s In db.Bills
                        Select s

        BillList.AddRange(BillQuery)

        ViewBag.BillId = New SelectList(BillList, "BillId", "BillDate")

        Return View(job)
    End Function

    '
    ' POST: /Job/Create

    <HttpPost()>
    Function Create(job As Job) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Jobs.Add(job)
            db.SaveChanges()

            Dim customer As Customer = db.Customers.Find(job.CustomerId)
            Dim customerNumber As String = customer.CustCellphone.ToString()
            Dim messageSender As SendMessage = New SendMessage
            Dim smsMessage As String = "LAUNDRY: Job Number " & job.JobId & " has been booked in. You will be notified when individual services within it are ready for collection."
            messageSender.SendMessage(smsMessage, customerNumber)

            Dim url As String = "/RequestedService/AddService/" + job.JobId.ToString()
            Return Redirect(url)
        End If
        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model Job doesn't have the property of BillId than in the view the dropdown markup should be

```
@Html.DropDownList("Job_BillId", ViewBag.BillId)
```

And the model Job contains the property BillId than create the ViewBag with some different name and use them accordingly in view markup for example:

Create a ViewBag with different name instead of BillId in controller

```
ViewBag.BillIdList =  New SelectList(BillList, "BillId", "BillDate")
```

And in view use this as below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BillId, ViewBag.BillIdList)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My model Job does have the BillId unfortunately tho so I do need to give it a default value?